# MSNP-Sharp Example fails to login, gives SocketException

Tags: c#, connection, socketexception, windows-live-messenger, msnpsharp

I've just downloaded the MSNP-Sharp library with the aim of creating my own messaging client, however I am struggling to get the example to sign in. The code all compiles and runs, but when I provide my login details and select "Login" I almost immediately get the following SocketException:

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 64.4.9.254:1863"

I've stepped through the code and it's the messenger.Connect() function that is causing this, somewhat obviously. When I run the example I only change the login and password details. I am running Windows 7 x86 with the latest version of Windows Live Messenger.

I have tried disabling my antivirus, even going as far as to temporarily uninstall it in case that was the error.

I have also tried disabling Windows Firewall, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

here is a demo,i hope it would be useful

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Drawing.Color;

  namespace MSNRobot
  {
    using MSNPSharp;
    using MSNPSharp.Core;
    using MSNPSharp.DataTransfer;

    class RobotConversation
    {
        private Conversation _conversation = null;
        private RobotMain _robotmain = null;

        public RobotConversation(Conversation conv, RobotMain robotmain)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==> Struct a conversation");
            _conversation = conv;
            _conversation.Switchboard.TextMessageReceived += new EventHandler<TextMessageEventArgs>(Switchboard_TextMessageReceived);
            _conversation.Switchboard.SessionClosed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Switchboard_SessionClosed);
            _conversation.Switchboard.ContactLeft += new EventHandler<ContactEventArgs>(Switchboard_ContactLeft);
            _robotmain = robotmain;
        }

        //online status
        private void Switchboard_TextMessageReceived(object sender, TextMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>Received Msg From " + e.Sender.Mail + " Content:\n" + e.Message.Text);

            //echo back ///////////// TODO /////////////////
            _conversation.Switchboard.SendTextMessage(e.Message);
        }

        private void Switchboard_SessionClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>Session Closed, Remove conversation");
            _conversation.Switchboard.Close();
            _conversation = null;
            _robotmain.RobotConvlist.Remove(this);
        }

        private void Switchboard_ContactLeft(object sender, ContactEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>Contact Left.");
        }
    }

    class RobotMain
    {
        private Messenger messenger = new Messenger();
        private List<RobotConversation> _convs = new List<RobotConversation>(0);

        public RobotMain()
        {
            messenger.NameserverProcessor.ConnectionEstablished += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(NameserverProcessor_ConnectionEstablished);
            messenger.Nameserver.SignedIn += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Nameserver_SignedIn);
            messenger.Nameserver.SignedOff += new EventHandler<SignedOffEventArgs>(Nameserver_SignedOff);
            messenger.NameserverProcessor.ConnectingException += new EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs>(NameserverProcessor_ConnectingException);
            messenger.Nameserver.ExceptionOccurred += new EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs>(Nameserver_ExceptionOccurred);
            messenger.Nameserver.AuthenticationError += new EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs>(Nameserver_AuthenticationError);
            messenger.Nameserver.ServerErrorReceived += new EventHandler<MSNErrorEventArgs>(Nameserver_ServerErrorReceived);
            messenger.Nameserver.ContactService.ReverseAdded += new EventHandler<ContactEventArgs>(Nameserver_ReverseAdded);
            messenger.ConversationCreated += new EventHandler<ConversationCreatedEventArgs>(messenger_ConversationCreated);
            messenger.Nameserver.OIMService.OIMReceived += new EventHandler<OIMReceivedEventArgs>(Nameserver_OIMReceived);
            messenger.Nameserver.OIMService.OIMSendCompleted += new EventHandler<OIMSendCompletedEventArgs>(OIMService_OIMSendCompleted);
        }

        public List<RobotConversation> RobotConvlist
        {
            get
            {
                return _convs;
            }
        }

        private void NameserverProcessor_ConnectionEstablished(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //messenger.Nameserver.AutoSynchronize = true;
            Console.WriteLine("==>Connection established!");
        }

        private void Nameserver_SignedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messenger.Owner.Status = PresenceStatus.Online;
            Console.WriteLine("==>Signed into the messenger network as " + messenger.Owner.Name);
        }

        private void Nameserver_SignedOff(object sender, SignedOffEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>Signed off from the messenger network");
        }

        private void NameserverProcessor_ConnectingException(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString(), "Connecting exception");
            Console.WriteLine("==>Connecting failed");
        }

        private void Nameserver_ExceptionOccurred(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // ignore the unauthorized exception, since we're handling that error in another method.
            if (e.Exception is UnauthorizedException)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine("==>Nameserver exception:" + e.Exception.ToString());
        }

        private void Nameserver_AuthenticationError(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>Authentication failed:" + e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
        }

        private void Nameserver_ServerErrorReceived(object sender, MSNErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // when the MSN server sends an error code we want to be notified.
            Console.WriteLine("==>Server error received:" + e.MSNError.ToString());
        }

        void Nameserver_ReverseAdded(object sender, ContactEventArgs e)
        {
            //Contact contact = e.Contact;
            //contact.OnAllowedList = true;
            //contact.OnPendingList = false;
            //messenger.Nameserver.ContactService.AddNewContact(contact.Mail);

            Console.WriteLine("==>ReverseAdded contact mail:" + e.Contact.Mail);

            //messenger.Nameserver.AddNewContact(
            e.Contact.OnAllowedList = true;
            e.Contact.OnForwardList = true;

        }

        private void messenger_ConversationCreated(object sender, ConversationCreatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>Conversation created");
            _convs.Add(new RobotConversation(e.Conversation, this));
        }



        //offline status
        void Nameserver_OIMReceived(object sender, OIMReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==>OIM received at : " + e.ReceivedTime + " From : " +
                e.NickName + " (" + e.Email + ") " + e.Message);

            TextMessage message = new TextMessage(e.Message);
            message.Font = "Trebuchet MS";
            //message.Color = Color.Brown;
            message.Decorations = TextDecorations.Bold;
            Console.WriteLine("==>Echo back");
            messenger.OIMService.SendOIMMessage(e.Email, message.Text);
        }

        void OIMService_OIMSendCompleted(object sender, OIMSendCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OIM Send Error:" + e.Error.Message);
            }
        }

        public void BeginLogin(string account, string password)
        {
            if (messenger.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("==>Disconnecting from server");
                messenger.Disconnect();
            }

            // set the credentials, this is ofcourse something every MSNPSharp program will need to implement.
            messenger.Credentials = new Credentials(account, password, MsnProtocol.MSNP16);


            // inform the user what is happening and try to connecto to the messenger network.  
            Console.WriteLine("==>Connecting to server...");
            messenger.Connect();

            //displayImageBox.Image = global::MSNPSharpClient.Properties.Resources.loading;

            //loginButton.Tag = 1;
            //loginButton.Text = "Cancel";

            // note that Messenger.Connect() will run in a seperate thread and return immediately.
            // it will fire events that informs you about the status of the connection attempt.
            // these events are registered in the constructor.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// main()
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string robot_acc = "";
            string robot_passwd = "";

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("USAGE:MSNRobot.exe <msn_account> [password]");    
                return;
            }

            robot_acc = args[0];

            if (args.Length == 2)
                robot_passwd = args[1];
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Password for " + robot_acc + ":");
                robot_passwd = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            RobotMain app = new RobotMain();
            app.BeginLogin(robot_acc, robot_passwd);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am a MSN robot:" + robot_acc);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I'm getting the same error. This is from your log (I removed the "I am a MSN robot" bit for clarity):


==>Connecting to server...

NSMessageProcessor: End Connect Callback

NSMessageProcessor: ** EndConnectCallback exception **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 64.4.50.62:1863

   at Org.Mentalis.Network.ProxySocket.ProxySocket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at MSNPSharp.Core.SocketMessageProcessor.EndConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)


==>Connecting failed

Comment: I should add that I did have to change the MSNP protocol used from MSNP16 to MSNP18 as MSNP16 wasn't recognised by my MSNP runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use the stable version of MSNPSharp (that is, 3.0). Since it is a SocketException, this may relate to a problem within the internet protocol (a firewall for instance). Try to ensure that nothing is blocking the program from accessing to the MSN protocol. Since you have said you have disabled your Windows Firewall, could there be anything else that could be blocking it?

Secondly, have you tried using MSN Messenger Live for a test. If that works, MSNPSharp client should probably work too. Ensure you have .NET Framework 2.0 or within their version of the .NET Framework. If it constantly appears to be a problem, I don't believe this is a problem from the MSNPSharp client (I'm not sure however).

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the example client for MSNPSharp?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am having the issue in.